# Assigning derived class array to base class pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
class B { 
public: 
 B () : b(bCounter++) {} 
int b; 
static int bCounter;  
}; 
int B::bCounter = 0; 
class D : public B { 
public: 
D () : d(bCounter) {} 
int d; 
}; 
const int N = 10; 
B arrB[N]; 
D arrD[N]; 
int sum1 (B* arr) { 
    int s = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
         s+=arr[i].b; 
    return s; 
} 
int sum2 (D* arr) { 
     int s = 0; 
     for (int i=0; i<N; i++) s+=arr[i].b+arr[i].d; 
     return s; 
} 
int main() { 
    std::cout << sum1(arrB) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << sum1(arrD) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << sum2(arrD) << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

The problem is in line 2 of main function. I expected that when sum1() function was called with argument arrD( which is an array of the Derived class objects), it would simply "cut off" the D::d, but in this case it rearranges the order in arrD, and the summing goes like this:
10+11+11+12+12+13+13+14+14+15
It seems to be alternating between b and d fields of arrD[i], and it should be summing up only b fields.
Can someone please explain why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have been unlucky enough to hit one of the sweet spots of the type system that allows to compile perfectly invalid code.

The function `int sum1 (B* arr)` takes a pointer to a `B` object as argument according to the signature, but semantically it really takes a pointer to an *array* of `B` objects. When you call `sum1(arrD)` you are violating that contract by passing not an *array* of `B` objects, but rather an *array* of `D` objects. How do they differ? Pointer arithmetic is done based on the size of the type of the pointer, and a `B` object and a `D` object have different sizes.

*An array of `D` is not an array of `B`*

In general, a container of a derived type is **not** a container of the base type. If you think about it, the contract of a container of `D` is that it holds, well, `D` objects, but if a container of `D` was a container of `B`, then you would be able to add `B` objects (if the argument was extending, you might even consider adding `D1` objects --also derived from `B`!).

If instead of raw arrays you were using higher order constructs, like `std::vector` the compiler would have blocked you from passing a `std::vector<D>` in place of a `std::vector<B>`, but why did it not stop you in the case of an array?

*If an array of `D` is not an array of `B`, why did the program compile at all?*

The answer to this predates C++. In C, all arguments to functions are passed by value. Some people consider that you can also *pass-by-pointer*, but that is just passing a pointer *by-value*. But arrays are *large*, and it would be very expensive to pass arrays by value. At the same time, when you dynamically allocate memory you use *pointers*, although conceptually, when you malloc 10 `int`s you are allocating an *array* of `int`. The designers of the C language considered this and made an exception to the pass by value rules: if you try to pass an array by value, a pointer to the first element is obtained, and that pointer is passed instead of the array (a similar rule exists for functions, you cannot *copy* a function, so passing a function implicitly obtains a pointer to the function and passes that instead). The same rules have been in C++ since the beginning.

Now, the next problem is that the type system does not differentiate from a pointer to an element when that is all there is, and a pointer to an element that is part of an array. And this has consequences. A pointer to a `D` object can be implicitly converted to a pointer to `B`, since `B` is a base of `D`, and the whole object of OO programming is being able to use derived types in place of base objects (well, that for the purpose of polymorphism).

Now going back to your original code, when you write `sum1( arrD )`, `arrD` is used as an *rvalue*, and that means that the array decays to a pointer to the first element, so it effectively is translated to `sum1( &arrD[0] )`. The subexpression `&arrD[0]` is a pointer, and a pointer is just a pointer... `sum1` takes a pointer to a `B`, and a pointer to `D` is implicitly convertible to a pointer to `B`, so the compiler gladly does that conversion for you: `sum1( static_cast<B*>(&arrD[0]) )`. If the function just took the pointer and used it as a single element, that would be fine, as you can pass a `D` in place of a `B`, but an array of `D` is not an array of `B`... even if the compiler allowed you to pass it as such.

Comment: Thus one should use Vectors or Spans according to C++ Core guidelines.Link - http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c152-never-assign-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-derived-class-objects-to-a-pointer-to-its-base

Answer (score 2):

The size of a `B` is smaller than a size of a `D`. So when `sum1` is iterating over the pointer `arr`, `arr[1]` is pointing at what it thinks is the 2nd `B` element in the array, which will actually be in the middle of the 1st `D` element.

So (assuming no padding), `arrD` has a layout like this:

```
arrD: | 2 ints    | 2 ints    | 2 ints    | ...
```

But, you set a `B *arr` to it, making `sum1` think it is an array of B. So `sum1` will think that the parameter has a layout like this:

```
arr:  | int | int | int | int | int | int | ...
```

So, `arr[1]` is actually the `d` member of `arrD[0]`.

Comment: how come the iteration doesn't stubmle on values in vtable then?

Comment: @YePhIcK: There is no vtable since there are no virtual methods.

Comment: indeed, you are correct. Silly me. I just automatically assumed `virtual` for the base class's destructor which was *meant* to be derived from :)

Comment: @YePhIcK: virtual in base class won't help you in this case. I suspect that it will be even worse.

Answer (score 2):

Your `arr` is of type `B*`, what this means is that `arr[i]` or `(arr + i)` would advance `sizeof(B) * i` in memory. The memory looks like this:

> **10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15** 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 20

And the for loop adds

> 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15

which is exactly what is the first elements in memory are, instead of advancing by the `sizeof(D) * i` like you want it.